# Native linking failed error in xamarin for GoogleSign

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am following this tutorial for GoogleSign in my project. https://www.pujolsluis.com/google-client-plugin-for-xamarin/
.Works fine in android. But getting Native linking failed errors while rebuild in ios.

```
Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID'   
Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB'   
Native linking failed. Please review the build log. 
Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'  
Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics'   
Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn'
Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore'
```

Deleted bin and obj folders in both mac and visualstudio; clean and rebuid; still error persists.Please help..

Diagnostic build output:

```
Xamarin.iOS 12.2.1 using framework: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk (TaskId:215)
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'GoogleSignIn' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseInstanceID' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseCore' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseAnalytics' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseNanoPB' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'GoogleSignIn' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseInstanceID' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseCore' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseAnalytics' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): warning MT1302: Could not extract the native library 'FirebaseNanoPB' from '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB'. Please ensure the native library was properly embedded in the managed assembly (if the assembly was built using a binding project, the native library must be included in the project, and its Build Action must be 'ObjcBindingNativeLibrary').
2>  Process exited with code 1, command: (TaskId:215)
2>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang  -framework Security -framework OpenGLES -framework GLKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework WebKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreVideo -framework CoreText -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AddressBook -framework AdSupport -framework StoreKit -weak_framework CoreSpotlight -weak_framework SafariServices -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework CFNetwork /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/registrar.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/main.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/login2.iOS.exe.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/mscorlib.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.iOS.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Mono.Security.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Xml.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Core.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Data.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Numerics.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/OpenTK-1.0.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Net.Http.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Web.Services.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/System.Xml.Linq.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Plugin.GoogleClient.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Google.SignIn.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Firebase.InstanceID.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Firebase.Core.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Firebase.Analytics.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/login2.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/arm64/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll.o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GTMOAuth2 /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleToolboxForMac /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/nanopb /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GTMSessionFetcher /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Protobuf /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.12/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.12/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libxamarin-debug.a -force_load /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.2.1.12/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/lib/libapp.a -ObjC -lsqlite3 -lc++ -lz -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -Wl,-pie -arch arm64 -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.4.sdk -liconv -o /Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Output/login2.iOS -dead_strip -u _xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type -u _xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr -u _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr -u _UIApplicationMain -u _kGIDSignInErrorDomain -u _kFIRInstanceIDScopeFirebaseMessaging -u _kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification -u _mono_pmip (TaskId:215)
2>  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn' (TaskId:215)
2>  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID' (TaskId:215)
2>  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore' (TaskId:215)
2>  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics' (TaskId:215)
2>  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' (TaskId:215)
2>  clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB' (TaskId:215)
2>   (TaskId:215)
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/GoogleSignIn'
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseInstanceID'
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCore'
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseAnalytics'
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics'
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/cybasetechnologies/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/login2.iOS/0f92dcc98e9717a0d2643ed70077af70/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/FirebaseNanoPB'
2>D:\visual studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
2>  Tool /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mtouch execution finished. (TaskId:215)
2>  MTouch: 2019-01-01T13:44:58.3411681+05:30 - Finished (TaskId:215)
2>Done executing task "MTouch" -- FAILED. (TaskId:215)
2>Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "login2.iOS.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:307)
```

Comment: Get the full build error and add it to your question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting#diagnostic-msbuild-output

Comment: @SushiHangover added diagnostic build output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now..All those 7 errors are missing nuget packages.Added all those in nuget solution and rebuild succeeds! i blindly followed the tutorial..